# Certification Error in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, j2mepolish

I have problem installing J2ME application in Nokia Phone.
When I install app from PC Suite it works fine, but when I upload file on my local server and try to download app it says that App is from Untrusted Supplier even though I have signed my Application. Please help me.

Comment: which certificates you are using /

Comment: check the date of the sign and if the mobile has actual date

Comment: @Lucifer why are you doing android retag?it is not Android

Comment: I havent done Android Retag oK

Comment: This kind of signing issues is what killed J2ME.

Comment: Are you installing with the jar or jad file in both cases?

Comment: @gorkem: no actually,i upload both jad and jar..but downloading only jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Your midlet is trusted only if it is installed using the JAD because jad includes the necessary information. Jar will still install but will not be trusted